# spark saveAsTextFile to s3 fails

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have a Spark process that takes two input files from S3. At the end of the job, I simply want to write the results back into S3 with `saveAsTextFile` method. However, I am getting `Access Denied` errors.

My policy rule is wide open to make sure I don't have any permission errors:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1457106962648",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1457106959104",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I set my credentials on `SparkContext` like the following:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("GraphAnalyser")
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .set("spark.driver.memory", "2G");
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", [access-key])
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", [access-key])
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", [secret-key])
                .set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", [secret-key]);
```

And I use pass file URLs with the `s3n` protocol:

```
final String SC_NODES_FILE  = "s3n://" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + NODES_FILE;
final String SC_EDGES_FILE  = "s3n://" + BUCKET_NAME + "/" + EDGES_FILE;
final String SC_OUTPUT_FILE = "s3n://" + BUCKET_NAME + "/output";
```

Note that I have no trouble with accessing the input files. It seems like Spark sends a `HEAD` request for the output file, to make sure it does not exist before it attempts to save final results. Since, s3 returns `Access Denied` instead of `Not Found`. That is probably the reason why Spark throws an Exception and exits.

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 HEAD request failed for '/output.csv' - ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden
```

Spark 1.6.0
aws-java-sdk (1.10.58)
spark-core_2.10 (1.6.0)

Your help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to check for the region settings ! AWS's API is quite painful and changes constantly and it's error messages are not quite descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*answering my own question*

It turns out that I needed the `s3:ListBucket` action, which is only applicable when resource is the bucket itself, not the keys inside the bucket.

In my original policy file I had the following resource:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
```

I had to add:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
```

Here's my final policy file that works for me:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy145712123124123",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt145712812312323",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>",
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/<user-name>"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```